# How do I Display row values in c# using access database?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, row, oledb

I am triyng to Make a program which shows the user random english words(taken from an access DB) and requires him to write the hebrew defenition of the word.
I managed to program this very easily using "cells(X,Y)" in excel VBA... But now when I am triyng to do it in c# and access I am getting a bit lost.
I managed to get the reader working - the question is - how to tell it read only a specific row in my project?
I.E. - it gets a random number of 5, and then it shows the value of the english word in row 5, and expects to recieve the hebrew word in row 5 as an answer.

this is what i currently achieved:

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Words\WordsDatabase.accdb";
            string mySelect = "SELECT english,hebrew FROM study";
            OleDbConnection dbConnect = new OleDbConnection();
            dbConnect.ConnectionString = conStr;
            dbConnect.Open();
            OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(mySelect, dbConnect);
            OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

`while (dbReader.Read())
        {
        textBox1.Text +=  dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString() + "\r\n";
        textBox2.Text += dbReader.GetValue(1).ToString() + "\r\n";

        }


    }`

Thanks a lot,
Barak.

Answer (score 0):

The question is SQL related really. Change the mySelect to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 english, hebrew FROM study ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is getting much better. The question now is how to refer in the "order by" part to an external function.

Comment: Sorry, missed the access bit. There's nothing like NEWID() in access, so your option is to use Rnd with the ID field of your table (hopefully autonumbred PK) if you've got it. You can use Anastasiosyal's version below or just go `SELECT TOP 1 english, hebrew FROM study ORDER BY Rnd(YOURSTUDYID)`

Comment: Thanks! It' getting there. The question now is - how te get the order, insead of totaly random - to work by a certain function I build?

Comment: Well in that case it's pretty much up to your function to handle everything (keeping track of already served ids, etc). So your SQL bit's gonna look like: `string mySelect = String.Format("SELECT english, hebrew FROM study WHERE studyID = {0}", YourFancyFunction());`

Answer (score 0):

The MS Access equivalent query would be:

```
SELECT TOP X english, hebrew FROM study ORDER BY Rnd(-10000000*TimeValue(Now())*[id])
```

Where

- [id] is the numeric (autonumber most likely) primary key field for study
- X is the number of rows you would like returned.

[Credit](http://forums.asp.net/t/1139860.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to control the order? i.e use a funcion that provides a certain number?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by controlling the order. I've edited the response so you can get X random records and you just iterate over them in the order that the database query responded. The english column will always correspond to the hebrew column

Comment: It should display one item... that is good. what I mean by controlling the order is - for instance, I don't want the order to be 100% random, but by a certain function that provides a number - and that number will be the ID of the chosen line.  (Lets say I don't want it to show the same row twice - I have to use a function for it). Thanks again.

Comment: You could add logic into your application so that it keeps a list of all the ids that you have already consumed. Therefore you could  either requery if you received a record you already processed, or you could  add a `WHERE ID not in (1, 5, 10, etc)` clause to guarantee that you will not be retrieving those processed records back again.